# ReverseProxy y SSL en drupal 10

Tags: apache, docker, ssl, proxy, drupal

tengo montado un servidor apache con SSL y con múltiples reverse proxy de apache que redireccionan a aplicaciones de docker internas que están mapeadas en distintos puertos.

Para poner un poco más de contexto es la web de pre producción, hago una redirección del puerto 880 (http) al 8443 (https) y desde el VirtualHost 8443 hago la redirección al puerto del contenedor.

La cuestión es que la respuesta que proporciona el apache (anfitrión) tiene SSL pero el contenedor de docker no detecta el SSL en ciertas peticiones POST y en ciertas variables, antiguamente drupal tenia la variable $base_url, pero en la versión 10 no, por lo que no puede hardcodear las variables.

Lo he intentado todo con .htaccess tanto de la máquina anfitrión como con el .htaccess del contenedor y estoy un poco perdido.

Hay muchos fallos de peticiones POST y variables con http, por lo que creo que es un fallo del SSL.

Gracias.

[image: SSL]

[image: No SSL]